# Docker v2.12.2 isn't showing echoes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am just trying to see an echo with my updated docker compose, but they are being hidden, I would like to ask if exist an option to remove that for debug purposes, I also tried:

```
docker-compose --verbose up
```

```
docker-compose --ansi "always" up
```

```
BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker-compose up
```

Any help will be welcome, I am stuck 2 days with this now and I cant see the echo, and I do need to debug this machine.

Cheers!

Comment: I think I could find the solution for this, I am using linux so to be able to change the way that we have the docker or docker-compose is to export a variable at the terminal, so docker can know what should be doing, so I did:

`export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain`

Answer (score 0):

I think I could find the solution for this, I am using linux so to be able to change the way that we have the docker or docker-compose is to export a variable at the terminal, so docker can know what should be doing, so I did: export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain

This we can get it back the previous echoes into dockerfile lines, so you can debug well while building docker machines.